# Как обратиться к методам через переменную

Tags: php, ооп

Собственно не получается обратиться к методам класса через переменную с другим методом.
Вот есть такой класс например

```
class Handler
{
    public function getHandler()
    {
        return 'some handler';
    }

    public function getFile()
    {
        return 'some file';        

}
}
```

Я создаю экземпляр класса `$class = new Handler();`
Метод `getHandler` доступен `$handler = $class->getHandler();`

А к методу `getFile()` хочу обращаться вот так
 `$file = $handler->getFile();` 
При таком обращении я получаю ошибку:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getFile() on
>   string

Конечно такое обращение `$file = $class->getFile();` работает, но я хочу, чтобы работала вот так `$file = $handler->getFile();`

Comment: Для чего тогда вы возвращаете строку? Что должен делать метод getHandler?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого надо в методе `getHandler` возвращать ссылку на текущий объект:

```
public function getHandler() {
    // {
    // возможно блок каких-либо действий
    // }
    return $this;
}
```

---

Возможно вы делаете что-то цепочки вызовов. Пример с `$this` может выглядеть так:

```
class TestClass {   
    public static $currentValue;

    private static $_instance = null;

    private function __construct() { }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (self::$_instance === null) {
            self::$_instance = new self;
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function toValue($value) {
        self::$currentValue = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function add($value) {
        self::$currentValue = self::$currentValue + $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function subtract($value) {
        self::$currentValue = self::$currentValue - $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function result() {
        return self::$currentValue;
    }
}
```

использование:

```
$result = TestClass::getInstance()
    ->toValue(5)
    ->add(3)
    ->subtract(2)
    ->add(8)
    ->result();

echo $result; // выведет 14
```

---

Это как пример. Предполагаю, что что-то подобное вы хотите использоваться в `getHandler()`

Comment: Спасибо да именно это и хотел реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере $handler несёт результат выполнения getHandler() - строку. Вы пытаетесь оперировать им как экземпляром класса, но он просто строковая(в данном случае) переменная и ничего не знает о классе, как и класс о ней.

По сути вашего вопроса - только так:

```
$handler = $class->getHandler();
$file    = $class->getFile();
```

Comment: в вопросе написано `Конечно такое обращение $file = $class->getFile(); работает, но я хочу, чтобы работала вот так $file = $handler->getFile();` :)

Comment: Звоню Расмусу. Отпишусь :)

Comment: плюс 1 на ответе. wtf?

Comment: Нет пророков в своём отечестве :)

Answer (score 1):

Для этого существуют [переменные переменных](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php). В вашем случае это будет выглядеть так:

```
$file = $$handler->getFile();
```

А getHandler должно возвращать название переменной у которой есть метод getFile.

Как пример, в PHP можно делать вызов функций по названию:

```
$function_name = 'getHandler';
$result = $file->{$function_name}();
```